# Is Queueing Uploads in Android a good idea?

Tags: android, networking, service, upload, queue

I am currently writing an Android app and I'm wondering whether queueing all unfinished uploads internally is a good idea.

Specifically I want to check whether I can upload my data right now and if not I want to add it to a queue in a service which keeps checking in the background whether it is possible to upload again.

The reason I'm asking this is because I know very little "professional" apps which implement this kind of behaviour and I wanted to know if anyone knows a reason for this, be it technically, permission-wise or else.

Comment: Square implemented Tape just for this sort of scenario: http://square.github.io/tape/

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same question and given how much I have cursed other apps for not having this feature, I went ahead and did exactly that in my app. I did not use a service tho, just a thread that retries uploads periodically and the thread is respawned after every attempt, as long there is an item in the queue. I would only add that be sure to give the user the ability to remove individual items from the reattempt queue. Otherwise, this feature itself gets annoying.